# Laravel sail not supported dependency error

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-sail

As a project manager and programmer, I like the idea of Laravel Sail. A single line of code installs a development environment without installing any application to the main host with help of Docker. `curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

My problem is, Laravel sail is only supporting PHP 7.4 and 8.0 for now. I want to manipulate a Google Sheet with this package to test an idea.

`composer require revolution/laravel-google-sheets`

unfortunately it depends on another package which requires php 7.2

```
    - pulkitjalan/google-apiclient[dev-master, 4.0.0, ..., 4.1.1] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I believe this package would work with 7.4 without an issue. Also I will just use it to test my idea. Is there a way to tell composer to ignore this dependency issue and install the packages?

Comment: Why not simply use PHP 7.4 if any dependency is not yet compatible with PHP 8?

Comment: It was my mistake. I changed php from 8 to 7.4 and restart docker but I see on the document that I need to rebuild the container. This package work on 7.4 without an issue.